# Sending push from parse server hosted in heroku

Tags: heroku, apple-push-notifications, parse-server

I am following standard tutorial for using parse server in heroku from here.

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Push

I have used development .p12 file. My code in parse server is like this.

```
   push: {
    ios: {
      pfx: 'mycert.p12', // The filename of private key and certificate in PFX or PKCS12 format from disk  
      bundleId: 'com.khantthulinn.example', // The bundle identifier associate with your app
      production: false // Specifies which environment to connect to: Production (if true) or Sandbox
    }
  }
```

I use this curl to send push notification. App Id and master key is changed to fake one.

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: QCsRSsKJTHs2YGi2BdBsLTLcf4U1JpQoRtTU9d0l
" \
    -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: XoEVsXstyWl3M8sJK1qO0ll1G5bWJpTUmhX90du1
" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{ 
        "where": { 
            "deviceType": { "$in": [ "ios",  "android"  ]  }  
        },
        "data": {
            "title": "Ant-man",
            "alert": "This is awesome. It is awesome."
        }
    }' \
    https://myexample.herokuapp.com/parse/push
```

In error logs, I have received like this.

> 2016-05-21T03:01:51.081259+00:00 app[web.1]: >
>   parse-server-example@1.4.0 start /app 2016-05-21T03:01:51.081265+00:00
>   app[web.1]: > node index.js 2016-05-21T03:01:51.081265+00:00
>   app[web.1]:  2016-05-21T03:01:52.581823+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   parse-server-example running on port 14168.
>   2016-05-21T03:01:52.698394+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to up 2016-05-21T03:03:15.488214+00:00 heroku[router]:
>   at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response"
>   method=POST path="/parse/push" host=myexample.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=0b5s4fbd-7258-4635-99a-178e37be15ce fwd="123.4.20.97"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=503 bytes=0

What do I need to set up in heroku?